# Emacs gets really slow when trying to compute battery status within mode-line-format

Tags: mode-line, powerline

While configuring [powerline](https://github.com/milkypostman/powerline), I use my own format for the mode-line. I now want to apply a different face to the battery load string, depending on the battery status (dis/charging). However, when I compute the charging status within my `mode-line-format` construct, Emacs gets really slow and I can't mark region with shift + arrow anymore.

You can see the mode-line definition in my configuration that I keep on Bitbucket: [init-mode-line.el:102](https://bitbucket.org/angrybacon/dotemacs/src/cfce24afb2139a10294154d7b923cc1fc697f80a/lisp/init-mode-line.el?at=master#cl-102).

The idea behind it was to have a boolean describing the battery status, and use it in the manner of `active`, that I already use.

Here is the output of `profile-report`:

[image: Profile report]

Comment: Did you try profiling `battery-status-function`? http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Profiling.html (here's the reference for how to do it, in case you need it).

Comment: This is a very good advice, I did not know that thank you :). Not sure how it can help me though. I have attached a screenshot of the  `profile-report` output. I guess each redraw of the mode-line opens the battery file and read from it, which seems to be resource demanding.

Comment: I don't know what `battery-pmset` does, but I would try memoisation, i.e. I'd try to store the old value somewhere and only poll the device once every couple of seconds or so.

Comment: Ended up using an advice, idea taken from `smart-mode-line.el`, but I'm depending on `battery-update-interval`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shamelessly taken from [smart-mode-line.el:1592](https://github.com/Malabarba/smart-mode-line/blob/master/smart-mode-line.el#L1592). The defadvice will colorize the battery load string before every call to `battery-update`.

```el
(defadvice battery-update (before my/pl-colorize-battery-advice activate)
  "Colorize the battery load string depending on its status (dis/charging)."

  (if (string-equal "AC" (cdr (assoc 76 (funcall battery-status-function))))
      (copy-face 'my/pl-battery-charging-face 'my/pl-battery-face)
    (copy-face 'my/pl-battery-discharging-face 'my/pl-battery-face)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code calls `battery-status-function` for every mode line update.  This function inherently slow, because it has to invoke external programs to obtain battery information.  Since Emacs is single-threaded, each invocation freezes Emacs until the function returns.  As the mode line is updated frequently, by almost every command, and often multiple times per command, these small delays amount to a very noticeable lag in all operations of Emacs, which renders Emacs almost entirely unusable.

I had the very same issue when I tried to customize the battery status appearance in my mode line, and wrote [fancy-battery.el](https://github.com/lunaryorn/fancy-battery.el) to address it.  This package queries and caches the battery status independently of mode line updates, and thus reduces the frequency of invocations of `battery-status-function`, removing the lag entirely.  It's written for the standard mode line, but it should work well with powerline, too.